# SQL query between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I have a database with 2 tables that I am working with (SugarCRM).

I am querying the table cases_audit to get a row count of cases with a status changed to closed. All this works great.

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to take the id from cases_audit and ensure that under table cases that same id has a type = "support"

```
// Query cases_aduit to find out how many cases were closed -0 days ago
$query_date_1_closed = "select * from cases_audit where after_value_string = 'Closed' and date_created LIKE '$date_1 %'";
$rs_date_1_closed = mysql_query($query_date_1_closed);
$num_rows_1_closed = mysql_num_rows($rs_date_1_closed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the column `id` in `cases_audit` referes to `id` in `cases` (which is not very likely), this query gives you every column from the audit plus `type` from the appropriate case:

```
SELECT
    A.*, C.type
FROM cases_audit A
    INNER JOIN cases C ON A.id=C.id
WHERE A.after_value_string = 'Closed' AND A.date_created LIKE '$date_1 %'
```

If you want to count the closed support cases, add `C.type` to your WHERE `condition`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM cases_audit A
    INNER JOIN cases C ON A.id=C.id
WHERE A.after_value_string = 'Closed' AND A.date_created LIKE '$date_1 %' AND C.type = 'support'
```

Answer (score 0):

`cases_audit.parent_id` is the field which relates to `cases.id`